# How do I create a function to change the value of the last node to 1000?

Tags: c++, linked-list

[image]

I tried to create a code for it. However, it didn't work. Here's my previous attempted code:

```
void modifyLastNode(node*) {
  curr = head;
  while (Curr != NULL && curr->data != 99) {
    temp = new node;
    temp->data = 1000;
    temp->next = curr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this code even compile? What is `Curr`?

Comment: `temp = new node;` in your loop why? Also why are `temp` and  `curr` not local variables?

Comment: Why does this function need a `node*` argument?

Comment: @cigien because that is part of the assignment given

Comment: I guess the better question about that is why is the parameter ignored?

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh right. Seems like OP doesn't know it's purpose though.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the *syntax* errors that prevent your code from even compiling properly (ie, `curr`, `head`, `Curr`, and `temp` are undefined), the code also contains several *logic* errors:

- You are ignoring the input parameter.
- You are not changing what `curr` points to while looping, so you end up checking the `data` field of the same `node` over and over, so you end up in an endless loop.
- You are allocating (and leaking) a new `node` on each loop iteration.  Searching should not be creating new `node`s at all.
- Checking the `data` field is the wrong way to detect the last node in the list.  The last node has its `next` field set to NULL, that is what you should be looking for.  Imagine calling `modifyLastNode()` twice on the same list.  The 1st call would look for `99` (which in your example is the last `node` in the list, but in a production system it may not be), changes it to `1000`, and then the 2nd call cannot find `99` anymore.

You need something more like this instead:

```c
void modifyLastNode(node *head) {
  if (head) {
    node *curr = head;
    while (curr->next != NULL) {
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->data = 1000;
  }
}
```